# How to see full email address in new Gmail compose (To: field)?

Tags: gmail

In the new compose for Gmail, the `To:` box will only show the nickname of a contact, but not the full address anymore. Is there a way to still automatically see the full email (mouse hover is not a good option)? Otherwise, the simplest solution for me is to erase all my contacts. When I revert to the old compose, it still properly shows the nickname AND full email.

Before:

```
To: "george" <tikitorch@stackoverflow.org>
```

Now:

```
To: george
```

Comment: I'm afraid not. That's just how the new compose works. Makes sense, since they're going for a less-cluttered look. Your only option, for now, is to switch back the old compose, but that will get retired soon.

Comment: so my best solution is really to delete all contacts?

Comment: Why do you want to delete all your contacts?

Comment: i want to make sure i am able to see the full email address in the to: field.  i just checked, and i don't actually have any contacts - gmail is pulling the names from the "other contacts".

Comment: so my issue is that i have emails from "george zimmer (george_old_email@yahoo.com)" and "george z (george_new_email@gmail.com)".  if i start a new email and type "george z" and hit return, it will autopopulate the email contact and just show the name.  now i'm not sure which george email i am using without mouse-over.  the "old compose" shows the name AND email address.

Comment: When I am entering names in the new compose, it shows the entire address that matches what I've entered so far.  Can you not just ensure that you pick the right one at that time?  My experience is that after a time or two of picking the right one, Gmail will guess correctly from then on.

Comment: i can check as i'm typing if i'm careful, and i have to remember to do that.  my issue is that it's just easier to see the email in the line.  i'm wondering if there is a selection or setting that i can default to show full email address.  looks like the answer is "use old compose form until it is removed".

Answer (score 3):

As Al mentions in the comments, there is no way to make new compose default to showing the whole email address. You'll have to switch back to old compose for the default feature.

You can however double-click the name tag/chip which will show you the contact info (name and email address) that is used. Double-clicking to see the email information is faster than hovering and waiting for the contact card to appear.

Double-clicking will also select the email information for you automatically so you can copy paste elsewhere if you need to. Clicking away will revert back to the name-only tag/chip.

Comment: thanks for this answer.  double clicking is nominally faster than mouse-over, but both require mouse motions which is less than ideal.  i'll just need to watch the email as i'm typing going forward.  thanks for your help!